# Xmarks limitations - How many is too many?

Tags: xmarks

Is there any documentation on the maximum number of bookmarks that Xmarks supports?

I am looking at setting up and using Xmarks to solve a issue with [de-duplicating bookmarks](https://superuser.com/questions/484770/de-duplicate-firefox-bookmarks).  I have a rather large set of bookmarks (~30,000).  Several years ago I had tried Xmarks, and it seemed to act very badly with a large set of bookmarks.

I am trying to figure out if Xmarks is just going to be able to handle my large selection of bookmarks.

Comment: @pnuts thanks.  I should probably just close this or something.  I have moved on and put most of the bookmarks I save on pinboard.in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Xmarks is a browser extension for managing bookmarks, not a web application.

Comment: I am not using it anymore and I never found a solution, so I don't mind closing.  On the other hand, it can be used purely via the web interface 'https://my.xmarks.com/' so it IS a web application.  Though my question wasn't really asked in that context.